# city is not populating in GA4 measurement protocol api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I want to manually record the `page_view` event from my application using Python, with the following data.

```json
{
    "client_id": "6909975079.1681323722",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "page_view",
            "params": {
                "page_title": "Wedding: QR Code",
                "hostname": "scan.example.com",
                "landing_page": "/eRCU",
                "page_location": "https://scan.example.com/eRCU",
                "page_referrer": "https://scan.example.com/eRCU",
                "city": "Mumbai",
                "continent_code": "AS",
                "country_code": "IN",
                "country": "India",
                "latitude": "19.0748",
                "longitude": "72.8856",
                "session_id": 1681313623,
                "engagement_time_msec": 264,
                "ip_address": "XX.36.XXX.14"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and sending the above data on the following endpoint

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-XXXXXXXX&api_secret=XXXXXuNRTXXXX7IiJXXXX
```

The event is recording successfully, however, the Geographic details are not auto-populating and adding as a custom event param.

[image]

[image]

How can I make geography details auto-populate?

Comment: have they changed something I thought the measurement protocol for ga4 did support location.   Can you post I link to it in the docs I can't find it

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately geo-information is only available via automatic collection (gtag, GTM, Google Analytics for Firebase).

We wont be able to supply it from the MP.